# Print variables from two object from two different class's, in a Arraylist,java

Tags: java, arraylist, transactions

I have a `accountclass` which has an `arraylist` that holds objects from two other classes. These classes are Deposit/Checks which are extended from a generic transaction class.

parent class:

```
Transaction(Double Amount,Int transactionType,Int transactionNumber)

//amount holds amount to be edited in the balance

//type =1,2,3;check,deposit,or fee

//number=number transaction in the account done.

check extends transaction;   
super(constructor)

deposit extends transaction
super(constructor);
```

Except that check has a variable, `checknumber` and deposit has two variables, check/cash which == amount to be edited.

When program is done,and prints summary I need to have these objects print their variables.

Before I had a simple `arraylist.get(i).getID, if ID == (the number I want)`

`print=arralist.get(i).getAmount(i)`, that was before they were separated classes,now that they are, separated i cant call each object, but how do i individually ask for that objects variable in the `arraylist`.

I cant do `arraylist.getobject.getcash` `arraylist.getobject.getcheck`

because that 'geter' is in the deposit class, not  in the account class,and those members are private so i cant simply add them to the `accountclass` where the `arraylist` sits.

So pretty much,

how to print member variables from objects which are in arraylist, that have different unique variables.

Comment: Post your code instead of converting it into English.

Answer (score 0):

The `instanceof` operator is what you're looking for. It will let you find out which class the element in the ArrayList belongs to, and then you can take the appropriate actions. Here's an example:

```
if(ArrayList.get(i) instanceof Check) {
    // take actions specific to checks
    String checkNum = ArrayList.get(i).getCheckNumber();
} 
if(ArrayList.get(i) instanceof Deposit){
    //take actions specific to deposits
    double cash = ArrayList.get(i).getCash();
}
etc...
```

Comment: Thank you, so if it is an instance ,could i then  double =arraylist.get(i).getcheck?

The problem is that once im in the Jpanel,referein the arraylist, im having trouble printing that objects variable from the method im in.

Comment: Yes, once you know what the instance is, you can call methods that are specific to that instance, such as ArrayList.get(i).getCheck(). I'll update my example.

Comment: thank you so much, ive searched and havent found a good way around it beside doing a new array and loops and having to write a bunch more code. I am at work and been thinking about this in my head all day. Will try it when i get home tonight.